# Remotely connect to Database in Container from Host Machine?

Tags: database, docker, macos, docker-compose, psql

I have a Psql running inside a container.
I can connect to via command line by running this

```
docker-compose exec api-db psql -U {username} {databasename}
```

[image]
But how can I connect to it via a GUI app

What should I use as a host ?

Is it possible ?

Comment: Have you published port 5432 in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I don't think my dev-ops team publish/allow this by default so it does not clash with the Dev’s local Postgre instance. Can I still publish it for my owned set up for owned local system just for a short period of time so I can connect to it, and can destroy/close that port back once done.

Comment: If you want to connect from "outside" the port must be published. You could of course publish any other port ("7777:5432") to prevent conflicts.

Comment: If you don't want to fiddle with docker-compose.yml you might want to create docker-compose-override.yml with an updated service definition: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that by "GUI app" you mean a postgres client like PgAdmin or your favorite IDE ?

You just have to configure your client datasource as we can see in your logs I mean :

```
host : localhost
port : 5432 (or the one mapped in your docker-compose.yml file)
database : It's not "monitor" as it doesn't find it !
user and password : in your docker-compose.yml too. Visibly it's not "root" as it doesn't find it.
```

Your docker-compose.yml should be at your project's root certainly.

If it's missing in your docker-compose you can add it with :

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  main:
    image: postgres:12.7-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=monitor
```

Best regards.